# Actual URL of AWS API gateway in Java Application deployed behind ELB

Tags: java, rest, url, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elb

I have Jersey 1.9 rest application deployed on tomcat servers(EC2). The tomcat servers are running behind the AWS ELB and API gateways for load balancing, caching and monitoring etc..

Flow of Calls to rest application is:
client --> API gateways --> ELB --> application (EC2-tomcat)

Client uses APi gateways URL to invoke the service. How can i get the actual API gateways URL that is used by client, in my application using Java(ws.core?) or UriInfo?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What part of the API gateway URL do you need? Hostname? Path? Query string? What problem are you solving with this information?

Comment: In my REST application, i have implemented pagination and for that i need to set next URL. Next URL would be complete URL of API gateway + some extra query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your NextURL comes as the request parameter API Gateway will simply pass it through to your Jersey application. You can look at the Jersey documentation example on how to define and retrieve request parameters inside your application: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2240

Comment: Thanks for Reply. In my Jersey application, my requirement is to created next URL. Suppose Client is hitting API gateway (https://www.apigateway-url.com/q=val1) and it goes to jersey application via load balancer . So in application i need to fetch complete URL (https://www.apigateway-url.com/q=val1) to create next URL(apigateway URL + some more query param) of the response .